# How do I know when a debit card is used for payment with Square Connect API?

Tags: square-connect

The Square Connect API has the following payment types:

```
    public enum TypeEnum
    {
        CREDITCARD = 0,
        CASH = 1,
        THIRDPARTYCARD = 2,
        NOSALE = 3,
        SQUAREWALLET = 4,
        SQUAREGIFTCARD = 5,
        UNKNOWN = 6,
        OTHER = 7
    }
```

According to their website they now support debit cards (at least in Canada). So I am wondering what payment type is returned if a debug card (Interac) is used for payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to know whether or not a card is a Debit or Credit card via Square's APIs.

Comment: So if they use debit, it just comes in as CREDITCARD. Thanks.

Comment: Generally you will just see `"type": "CARD",` in the response, I'm not sure where you are geeting that enum.

Comment: The enum is from the C# Square.Connect SDK nuget package made by Square.

Comment: ah, I recommend using the v2 endpoints to pull your transaction data.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, in the V1 api, it shows up as type Credit Card, with a CardBrand of INTERAC.  Unfortunately the .Net api is broken, as it does not include INTERAC in the CardBrand enum, so you won't be able to use it. I submitted a patch to Square over a month ago, but they haven't accepted it.